# How do I pull specified excel rows from a Boolean True selection using R?

Tags: r, excel, count, boolean, data-extraction

I initially pulled an excel file

```
library(readxl)

EXCEL_FILE <- read_excel("Excel_file.xlsx")
```

The initial file 
has a column with text and its length is up to 100. I created a script that is able to recognize specific words in that text like "Yes" or "No".

```
library(dplyr)

Count<-agrepl("Yes",EXCEL_FILE$Narrative)|agrepl("No",EXCEL_FILE$Narrative)
```

I get a count of TRUE values that the argument fulfills. The next step i would like to do is have an R script recognize those "True" rows and pull the whole row into a new excel file.

I know how to pull a file, so i need a script in between the previous and the following one.

```
library(xlsx)

write.xlsx(EXCEL_FILE, file= "Complete.xlsx")
```

Comment: And what have you tried since now to realize the selection of TRUE values?

Comment: the script above where it says Count <-agrepl..... will tell me the count values. It will say 33 for example. I want to pull those rows.